# What's the right way to cancel non-blocking socket operation on Solaris notified by completion port?

Tags: sockets, solaris

On Linux/epoll and FreeBSD/kqueue, shutdown() works as follows.

```
shutdown(connection, SHUT_RDWR);
```

Unfortunately, it does not work on Solaris/port to cancel the connect() operation. I tried out that ioctl() works.

```
ioctl(connection, I_SETSIG, S_HANGUP);
```

Is this the right way?